# indexPath has no value in Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view displaying a list of contacts and when you click a cell, a detail view controller pops up with labels showing the contact name, number, fax, and address. My problem is that every time I click a cell, the first value in the plist pops up no matter which cell i click. I found my error in indexPath when `NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);` returned `null` everytime. I think the problem is in this method but it looks the same in other classes and works fine.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCountyInfo"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
        TSPBookCoverViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.countyName = [[self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];//error
        destViewController.phoneName = [[self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Phone"];
        destViewController.faxName = [[self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fax"];
        destViewController.addressName = [[self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Address"];
    }
}
```

When I enter integers instead of `indexPath.row`, it works like it should, so the problem is here I just can't find it. Sorry if it's obvious I've tried looking for awhile now!

Edit:
Here is didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // Perform Segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCountyInfo" sender:self];   
}
```

Comment: That means your table view has no selected row at the time this code is called.

Comment: @rmaddy I thought the code was called when I selected a row that called this method

Comment: @MeredithCaveney: Can you add the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the following code:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

You are deselecting the cell inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. So the `indexPathForSelectedRow` will always return nil

Comment: Yes. By the time the segue performs, the cell is no longer selected.

Comment: Thank you! I took it out and it works! So every time I selected a row I would deselect it immediately? also do I need to put the code in another place?

Comment: @MeredithCaveney: I don't think you need to put that code in any other place (It depends on your implementation). If the `showCountyInfo` segue is not performed anywhere outside from didSelect method. You don't have to worry about the deselect issue. Else you can deselect the tableview in the `prepareForSegue:` method

Answer (score 0):

Best way for you to resolve it is to get the Dictionary from self.books array in

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and then perform the segue and get values from that dictionary in prepareForSegue